# Deployment of Spring web application using modules only shows "Not Found"

Tags: spring-mvc, deployment, module, wildfly-8

I would love to serve Spring Web MVC as a module in Wildfly but somehow the servlet (`WebApplicationInitializer`) doesn't seem to be starting.

#### module.xml

`modules/org/springframework/4.0.0.RELEASE/module.xml`

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.springframework" slot="4.0.0.RELEASE">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-context-support-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-mobile-device-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
  </resources>
</module>
```

Then I went back to my Maven project and scoped all dependencies with scope `provided`. When deploying the project in Wildfly everything seems to be ok.

`20:47:27,166 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-13) Adding dependency ModuleDependency [identifier=org.springframework:4.0.0.RELEASE, moduleLoader=Service Module Loader, export=true, optional=false, importServices=false] to module deployment.myapp.war:main`

`20:47:27,257 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /myapp`

`20:47:27,269 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (XNIO-1 task-7) JBAS018559: Deployed "myapp.war" (runtime-name : "myapp.war")`

Applications deployed with the Spring libraries bundled run fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution for this issue? I'm getting exactly the same behaviour and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The question related to [27545230](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545230/spring-webapplicationinitializer-not-working-in-wildfly-8-2-0-ear-deployment?rq=1) from which i got the solution.

Based on [https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12555](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12555?focusedCommentId=110788&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-110788) i created a jar with the services and managed to start the Spring application.